# Android studio .h file can't find the systerm repository

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I create a c++ project with CMake in Android Studio. Everything is ok when I use the old version IDE. After I upgraded it, the header file can't find the system repository eg: `<string.h>`. But the header file I created still found it in old version IDE.

The .cpp file still finds the system repository, but change it to the .h file. It turned red. Follow is my code. The EglCore.h file is created in the old version IDE. The EglCore2.h file is copied in new version IDE.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]